# How to get the second max and third max records of date column in sas

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I want to get the max, second max and third max date of below table

```
proc SQL;

create table Kri_obs_l(
  Kri_rk int,
  value_dt datetime,
  score int
);

insert into Kri_obs_l
values (10000, "2Jan2018"d, 12)
values (10001, "2Jan2018"d, 2)
values (10001, "29Jan2019"d, 18)
values (10002, "2Jan2018"d, 5)
values (10002, "26Jan2019"d, 18)
values (10002, "27Jan2019"d, 18)
values (10003, "2Jan2018"d, 18)
values (10003, "26Jan2019"d, 18)
values (10003, "27Jan2019"d, 18)
values (10004, "2Jan2018"d, 25)
values (10005, "2Jan2018"d, 32)
values (10005, "26Jan2019"d, 18)
values (10005, "27Jan2019"d, 18)
values (10006, "2Jan2018"d, 5)
values (10007, "2Jan2018"d, 2)
values (10008, "2Jan2018"d, 12)
values (10009, "2Jan2018"d, 18)
values (10009, "26Jan2019"d, 18)
values (10009, "27Jan2019"d, 18)
;
quit;
```

My Code to get the max, second max, and third max

```
proc sql;
create table KRI_score_max as
select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt) as reported_dt format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l
group by Kri_rk;

create table KRI_score_second_max as
select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt) as reported_dt format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l a
where value_dt = (select MAX(value_dt) from KRI_OBS_l b where value_dt< (select MAX(value_dt) from KRI_OBS_l))
group by Kri_rk;

create table KRI_score_third_max as
select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt) as reported_dt format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l
where value_dt < (select MAX(value_dt) from KRI_OBS_l where value_dt< (select MAX(value_dt) from KRI_OBS_l))
group by Kri_rk;

create table KRI_score_third_max as
select * 
from KRI_score_third_max
where KRI_rk in (select Kri_rk from KRI_score_second_max);

quit;
```

getting the max record is working fine, I'm having the issue in getting the second max and third max record
if I remove the 29Jan2019 record from the table it works fine, but adding that record makes 27Jan2019 the second max record so query gets this record as the second max. 
I want to get the second max and third max record of every record group by Kri_rk.

Since there is not any limit function in proc SQL, I can't use order by desc and limit combination.

Comment: sample output would be great

Comment: What about `ROWNUM <= 3 and order by value_dt` instead of Limit and order by? I have read also about `outobs` or `obs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple proc rank should work

```
proc rank data=Kri_obs_l out=inter descending ties=dense;
   by  Kri_rk;
  var value_dt ;
  ranks value_dt_1; 
 run; 

data final(drop=value_dt_1);
  set inter;
 if value_dt_1 le 3;
 run;
```

Assuming if you do not have duplicates in dates per id then below queries should work too

```
  proc sort data =Kri_obs_l out =Kri_obs_l_1;
     by  Kri_rk descending value_dt;
   run;

  data want;
    set Kri_obs_l_1;
  by  Kri_rk descending value_dt;
 if first.Kri_rk then m=1;
 else m+1;
   if m le 3;
 drop m;
   run;


   proc sql;
  create table want(drop=cnt) as 
     select Kri_rk, value_dt, score,
       (select count(value_dt) from Kri_obs_l a
    where a.Kri_rk = b.Kri_rk
   and a.value_dt ge b.value_dt
   group by Kri_rk) as cnt
   from Kri_obs_l b 
   where calculated cnt le 3
   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number()` window function if you want 1st to 3rd max date

```
select * from 
(
select * ,row_number() over(partition by Kri_rk order by value_dt desc) rn
from table_name
) t where t.rn<=3
```

Comment: over function is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude results from first created table in second statement, then exlude first two table from third query.

```
proc sql;
create table KRI_score_max as
select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt)  first_max as reported_dt format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l
group by Kri_rk;

create table KRI_score_second_max as
select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt) second_max as reported_dt  format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l a
where (kri_rk, value_dt) not in (select kri_rk, first_max from KRI_score_max)
group by Kri_rk
UNION ALL 
select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt) second_max as reported_dt format=date9. from KRI_OBS_l a group by Kri_rk having count(1)<2;

create table KRI_score_third_max as
select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt) third_max as reported_dt format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l
where (kri_rk, value_dt) not in (select kri_rk, first_max from KRI_score_maxl UNION ALL select kri_rk, second_max from KRI_score_second_max)
UNION ALL  
(select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt) third_max as reported_dt format=date9. from KRI_OBS_l a group by Kri_rk having count(1)<3
MINUS
select Kri_rk,second_max from KRI_score_max); 

quit;
```

Comment: Second max code is showing the max values of rows who has more than two value.

Comment: create table KRI_score_second_max as
select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt) second_max as reported_dt  format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l a
where (kri_rk, value_dt) not in (select kri_rk, first_max from KRI_score_max)
group by Kri_rk UNION ALL
select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt) second_max as reported_dt  format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l a group by Kri_rk having count(1)<2; and so for third query.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SAS, then make use of the `idgroup` functionality in `proc summary`.  The following code will store the top 3 dates per group, in separate columns (although you don't make it clear exactly how you want the data stored).

```
proc summary data=Kri_obs_l nway;
class kri_rk;
output out=want (drop=_:)
    idgroup(max(value_dt) out[3] (value_dt) = reported_dt);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot options to solve this. I prefered reuse your code and make adjust in your proc sql. I run the code below and it worked out.

```
proc sql;
create table KRI_score_max as
select Kri_rk, MAX(value_dt) as reported_dt format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l
group by Kri_rk;
quit;

proc sql;
create table KRI_score_second_max as
select a.Kri_rk, MAX(a.value_dt) as reported_dt format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l a
where a.value_dt not in (Select reported_dt from Kri_score_max b where 
a.kri_rk=b.kri_rk)
group by a.Kri_rk;

quit;

proc sql;
create table KRI_score_third_max as
select a.Kri_rk, MAX(a.value_dt) as reported_dt format=date9.
from KRI_OBS_l a
where a.value_dt not in (Select reported_dt from Kri_score_max b where 
a.kri_rk=b.kri_rk) and 
a.value_dt not in (Select reported_dt from KRI_score_second_max b where 
a.kri_rk=b.kri_rk) 
group by a.Kri_rk;
quit;
```